# Bug in "Saving" in the review process

Tags: bug, review, bookmarks, saves

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to the page of any specific review task, i.e. `https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/<review-id>`.
2. Click the “Saving” button.
3. Click the “Next Task” button.
4. Return to the previous page by either: (a) clicking the browser button or (b) pasting the link in the address and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Click the “Saving” button again.

**Symptoms:**

1. After Step 4, the “Saving” button becomes white again as if the post were not saved, and forced refreshing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) does not help.
2. After Step 5, the “Saving” button cannot becomes green, and a banner pops up showing “An error occurred.”

Comment: Strange, I don't see a “Saving” button on a close review page.

Comment: FYI, a somewhat related network Meta post is [The new "Saves" icon does not work in the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382710), and also this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383161) to [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019).

Comment: Ah, so this is about the “Save this question” icon? Anyways, if this affects all sites and not only Math SE then it is perhaps better posted on the global Meta site.

Comment: @MartinR I don't have an associated account on the meta site and IIRC site mods can elevate bug reports to the SE team.

Comment: The Saves icon has now been removed from the review queues, according to a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves/383254#comment1279516_383185) by an SE staff member.